# Efficient XOR sum operation (Matlab or C/C++)

Tags: matlab, sum, intel, xor

I have a following problem: I have tens and hundreds of thousands of 512bit logical arrays (or 64 bytes). For each possible pair I must perform XOR followed by sum. Is there a way to do that efficiently? I heard that there are special CPU instructions for this but my Google searches failed even to find the mention of it.

In ideal, I would like to do that in MATLAB. If not, I have also access to Intel's C++ compiler with IPP and TBB.

I would like to avoid for loops over each logical array element if possible.

Comment: Your problem sounds like a good candidate for a MEX function, but Matlab may be fast enough.  I would write one in simple Matlab, make sure it's working, and test its speed.  If it's too slow, write a simple C version first, debug it, and test its speed using maximum compiler optimization (`-O3` for gcc on Linux and Mac, I don't know about icc or Windows).  If it's still not fast enough, you should start looking at MMX and SSE instructions.  In particular, Google for 'Intel compiler intrinsics.'  But, seriously, first get a working version in straight Matlab, only optimize it if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Without for loops over the array elements, try:

```
x=[true true false false]
y=[true false true false]

z=xor(x,y)
sum(z)
```